# Cprofile (Python) in C++?

Tags: python, c++

When writing code In Python I usually use Cprofile which prints the profile results in the console:

```
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

#do stuff

pr.disable()
s = StringIO.StringIO()
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats('cumulative')
ps.print_stats()
print s.getvalue()
```

**Is there any alternatives in C++?**

Edit - I'm using VS 2008 Express, Windows 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to `Analyze -> Profiler -> Attach/Detach`.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind, specifically callgrind, is pretty much the standard way of doing this in C++. It's a little more complicated than python though, since python can basically monkey patch all calls to every method to generate call graphs and stuff.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html

Comment: I heard about Valgrind but the code looked soo complicated, would you mind adding a sample, like shown in my question?

Comment: @PeterParker It's not really that simple, and it doesn't really require modification of your code. It's just a program you run on your code. valgrind is an incredibly complex tool and I'm sure there are examples online.

Comment: Yes, but I need to run it inside my code, like in the question.